# What's wrong with Nexus 5x and hangouts?

Tags: android, sms, google-hangouts

My android app doesn't work on my phone. I have a Nexus 5x but it works on two of my friend's phone, which is a Samsung Galaxy S6 and LG V10. I have no idea what is going on. I can send messages but I cannot receive only on my phone. On my friend's phones, they can send, receive, do everything I want.

I have done some research and found that when type of the SMS message is 2, it means that its a message I sent. When it's 1, its a message I've received. On my phone, I get, MAYBE, one or two 1's but everything else is a 2 which shouldn't be the case because I know I've received a lot of texts. I do use Google Hangouts as my default messenger although the app I'm working on I want to be the default app. I have the priority set to 999 and still I can't read messages I've received.

Here is my manifest code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app.easy.text.texteasy">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="TextEasy"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming SMS messages -->
    <receiver android:name=".Receiver.SmsReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION" />
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_DELIVER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- BroadcastReceiver that listens for incoming MMS messages -->
    <receiver android:name=".Receiver.MmsReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_WAP_PUSH">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_DELIVER" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Service that delivers messages from the phone "quick response" -->
    <service
        android:name=".HeadlessSmsSendService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:scheme="sms" />
            <data android:scheme="smsto" />
            <data android:scheme="mms" />
            <data android:scheme="mmsto" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="TextEasy">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ContactList.Contacts"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_contacts"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"/>
</application>
```

Thank you for taking time to look at this. I would love to get some help because I've been pulling my hair out.

Comment: Are you using Google Fi on your device?

Comment: Ya I am using Google Fi

Comment: Yeah, Fi and Hangouts does something funky with SMS. I've had no direct experience with it, but it somehow either intercepts the incoming messages' broadcasts (which shouldn't be possible), or forces some other comm protocol for them. Try setting your app as the default SMS app, and disabling conversation merging in Hangouts' Settings, along with any other SMS-related stuff that might be there. (I've not updated Hangouts for forever, so there might be some other newer Settings I'm not aware of.)

Comment: I see. I have done that, and it still wasn't working. I had my suspicions that it had something to do with Google Fi.Is there any work around or am I just screwed?

Comment: The only other time I discussed this with a user, that's all they needed to do, apparently. As I mentioned, I've not had any first-hand experience with Fi/Hangouts, so about the only other thing I could suggest would be to try force stopping/turning off Hangouts from its app page in Settings, at least for the purposes of testing. You might do a reboot, too.